# OpenLayers display feature property on map on Select interaction

Tags: openlayers

I have working feature select interaction on pointerMove working and highlighting feature.
One more thing that I would like to get is to display feature property on selected feature.

 I would like to get on map on that particular feature not on new HTML element or popup
Worked out of example at http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html

Any help or ideas more that welcome :)

```
roomsLayerEventMouserOver(layer)  {
    if( this.select ){
        this.map.removeInteraction(this.select);
    }

    this.select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
        layers: [
            layer
        ],
        style: this.getStyle('pink', 'red'),
    });

    this.map.addInteraction(this.select);
    this.select.on('select', (e) => {
        let features = e.target.getFeatures();
        features.forEach( (feature) => {
            console.log(feature.getProperties().name);
           // THIS IS PROBABLY THE PLACE I NEED SOMETHING
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution for above:

```
roomsLayerEventMouserOver(layer)  {
    if( this.select ){
        this.map.removeInteraction(this.select);
    }

    this.select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
        layers: [
            layer
        ],
        style: (feature) => { return this.roomsSelectedFeatureStyle(feature); }

    });

    this.map.addInteraction(this.select);
}


roomsSelectedFeatureStyle(feature) {
    let roomNumber = feature.getProperties().name ? feature.getProperties().name : " ";
    let style;

    style = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: roomNumber
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: LAYER_ROOM_HIGHLIGTH_COLOR_BORDER,
            width: 1
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: LAYER_ROOM_HIGHLIGTH_COLOR_FILL
        })

    });

    return style;
}
```